# Require and Call something inside a object propertie

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to require and call an function inside a propertie and pass other propertie of the same object:

```
var Events = {
    api: true,
    path: '/api/events',
    model: require('../models/EventModel')(mongoose),
    controller: require('../controllers/EventController')(Events.model)
};
```

And is returning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

I already try to pass this.model also, but i think the THIS is referring to the global, and not the object, right?

Is possible achieve what i want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `controller` to a [**getter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```
var Events = {
    api: true,
    path: '/api/events',
    model: require('../models/EventModel')(mongoose),
    get controller() { return require('../controllers/EventController')(this.model)}
};
```

Comment: ecma5 or 6? never see this before haha

Comment: are you working for Stack or something like this? You are ALWAYS here hahahahaha <3

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, I wish. Im guessing its a coincidence and we are in similar timezones. Keep up the good questions

Answer (score 1):

`Event` hasn't been created yet by the time you try to use it.

Why not store it in a variable first?

```
var eventedMongoose = require('../models/EventModel')(mongoose);

var Events = {
    api: true,
    path: '/api/events',
    model: eventedMongoose,
    controller: require('../controllers/EventController')(eventedMongoose)
};
```